# Same style over the whole document for a specific word

Tags: formatting

I am writing my thesis and I'm looking for a way of displaying the project name with the same style all over the place. More specifically, when I'm writing 'MyProjectName' it should always be printed with bold font (just an example).

How can I defined the style for a single word/phrase. Is OK if I need to create a new command for it or something, I just want to avoid copy/pasting the style definition all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\NAME}{\mbox{\normalfont\bfseries MyProjectName}}
```

The `\mbox` is there in order to avoid that the name is split across lines; inside the box you can set whatever font you like, just remember to choose `\normalfont` first that sets the setting to the standard one.

Comment: You might want to add `\xspace` (`xspace` package) at the end of the macro.

Comment: @Martin: Bela Lugosi used to say "I never drink … wine"; I say "I never use `\xspace`". :)

Comment: But Victor might drink wine and/or want the functionality  of `\xpace` :-)

Comment: That works great! Wrt to `\xspace` I haven't decided yet :)